# TypeError: string payload expected: <class 'bytes'>

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using **Python 3.2**.
I **wrote a build log file** by using the following code:

```
rsltFile = open('buildLog.txt', 'wb')
    p = subprocess.Popen('call ant compile', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    for line in p.stdout.readlines(): 
        rsltFile.write(line) 
    retval = p.wait()
```

Then I am using the following to **send an email with above file attached**:

```
def send_mail(send_from, send_to, subject, text, files=[], server="XXX.XXX.com"):
  assert type(send_to)==list
  assert type(files)==list

  msg = MIMEMultipart()
  msg['From'] = send_from
  msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join(send_to)
  msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
  msg['Subject'] = subject

  msg.attach( MIMEText(text) )

  for f in files:
    part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
    part.set_payload( open(f,"rb").read() )
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(f))
    msg.attach(part)

  smtp = smtplib.SMTP(server)
  smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
  smtp.close()
```

but I **got the following error**:

```
  File "C:\workspace\VCT2400_Service\ServiceApplication\autobuild\myMail.py", line 29, in send_mail
    smtp.sendmail(send_from, send_to, msg.as_string())
  File "C:\Python32\lib\email\message.py", line 168, in as_string
    g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\email\generator.py", line 91, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\email\generator.py", line 137, in _write
    self._dispatch(msg)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\email\generator.py", line 163, in _dispatch
    meth(msg)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\email\generator.py", line 224, in _handle_multipart
    g.flatten(part, unixfrom=False, linesep=self._NL)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\email\generator.py", line 91, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\email\generator.py", line 137, in _write
    self._dispatch(msg)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\email\generator.py", line 163, in _dispatch
    meth(msg)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\email\generator.py", line 192, in _handle_text
    raise TypeError('string payload expected: %s' % type(payload))
TypeError: string payload expected: <class 'bytes'>
```

Comment: This appears highly related: http://bugs.python.org/issue4768

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file.read (when opened in 'rb' mode) in Python 3 return bytes, you need to either open the file in 'rt' mode or use decode the bytes to a string.

I highly recommend watching http://pyvideo.org/video/948/pragmatic-unicode-or-how-do-i-stop-the-pain